# Django manytomany field in admin - how to add a default list?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add a default list of items in the manytomany field in the case where it is left blank when updating in admin.

My problem is that changing the manytomany field by overriding save, save_model or the post_save signal doesn't work because django hasn't finished saving the child relations yet, only the parent (eg. [Django: Custom Save method for Many-to-Many relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988946/django-custom-save-method-for-many-to-many-relation)).  I tried the signal m2m_changed, a solution suggested in other posts, will not be triggered because if the list is left blank, it will not have changed!

Can anyone think of another approach as I seem to have reached a dead end with method overrides and signals?  I don't mind if the default list is added before or after the form is displayed in admin.

**UPDATE**

**What didn't work:**

(Fixtures is the name of my m2m field).

I've tried the suggestions below, overriding various methods.
From this trace you can see that the fixtures have been added and are visible through many methods of admin and the model, but they will be deleted and replace sometime after these methods are called.  There does not seem to be a after_everything_else method that can be overridden.

```
[Wed Sep 18 15:24:06 2013] [error]  in save of model fixture count =  0
[Wed Sep 18 15:24:06 2013] [error]  in save of overriden admin model form  fixture count =  15
[Wed Sep 18 15:24:06 2013] [error]  in save_model of admin fixture count =  15
[Wed Sep 18 15:24:06 2013] [error]  in save of model fixture count =  15
```

**What did work**

Overriding the admin form and putting the clean_fixtures method in there.  clean_fixtures will NOT be called in it is just put in the admin resource, it has to be in an overriden form like this:

```
class RankingUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def clean_fixtures(self):

        data = self.cleaned_data['fixtures']

        # add default set of fixtures if none already there
        if len(data) == 0:

            return get_default_fixtures()

        else:
            return data

class RankingUpdateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


    list_display = ('rank_type','date', 'comment', 'issued')
    form = RankingUpdateForm


    def clean_fixtures(self):

         assert False, "I'm never called!"

    def save_formset(self):
         assert False, "I'm never called either!"
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you do the changes in the save method of the model either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the Admin Form and implement the logic in the form clean method for your ManyToMany field. For eg.

```
def clean_recipients(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']

    if not data:
        # return default recipients if the selected list is empty.
        data =  [r.pk for r in Recipient.objets.all()]  #just an example, you can alter this query to select your defaults

    return data
```

### Update

Override the save method to save recepients

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self, False)

    old_save_m2m = self.save_m2m
    def save_m2m():
       old_save_m2m()
       instance.recepient_set.clear()
       for recepient in self.cleaned_data['recepients']:
           instance.recepient_set.add(recepient)
    self.save_m2m = save_m2m

    if commit:
        instance.save()
        self.save_m2m()

    return instance
```

Comment: This is not getting called as there are no m2m objects on the initial record when it is saved.

Comment: This should certainly be getting called because its just a clean method on the form, you could check with log statements. The problem could be that the recepients are not saved even after this because save_m2m method is not being called. In that case you could use the save method above to manually save the recepients.

Comment: The first option, once I ready your answer properly and put the form override in did work.  The second solution suffered the overwritten later problem.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet of code I used to auto populate an author in an admin formset if it was not set

```
class AutoAuthoredModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.author is None: 
            obj.author = request.user
        super(AutoAuthoredModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change): 
        if hasattr(formset.model, 'author'):
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                if instance.author is None:
                    instance.author = request.user
        super(AutoAuthoredModelAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

Comment: This suffers from the problem that m2m objects are all deleted and rewritten AFTER this happens.  sigh.

Comment: No, wait, this example caters for `ForeignKey`s, but can be adapted to M2M. For example, if the field was `authors` instead of `author`, I would check that `not obj.authors.all().exists()` then do `authors.add(any author)` for each default author. This would work the same for the `save_formset` method.

Comment: It seems that foreign keys are not treated in the same way as m2m.  See comments above.  Thanks for your help - I nearly rewrote to use foreign keys instead of m2m and will do that next time but having had these two answers I had to work this one out!

Comment: PhoebeB: that problem should be resolved in Django 1.6+.